# Using vertical whitespace character as java scanner delimiter scans empty string at each endline

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan in a file with data fields delimited either by '@' or 'endline' using the Scanner class in Java.  Here is a sample input file:

```
Student @ Codey @ Huntting
Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger
```

To properly scan an input file that looks like this, I've tried to change the delimiter on the Java scanner to the regular expression `"[@\\v]"`, which should match either `@` or any vertical whitespace, including `\n` and `\r`according to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)

Here is the code that I'm using to test it out:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data/initialize.txt"));
int tokenNum = 0;

scanner.useDelimiter("[@\\v]");

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Token #" + tokenNum++ + ": " + scanner.next());
}

scanner.close();
```

The tokens I'm expecting to scan are:

```
Token #1: Student
Token #2:  Codey 
Token #3:  Huntting
Token #4: Student
Token #5:  Sarah
Token #6:  Honsinger
```

But the tokens actually received are:

```
Token #1: Student
Token #2:  Codey 
Token #3:  Huntting
Token #4
Token #5: Student
Token #6:  Sarah
Token #7:  Honsinger
Token #8:
```

I would have expected the Scanner, upon scanning `Huntting`, to move up to the newline after Huntting and, on the next call to `input.next()`, skip over that newline, but for some reason the scanner appears to be grabbing an empty string there at the end of the line.

I've checked multiple times and the file does not have any spaces after any of the lines.  I've tried different patterns like `[@[\\v]]` and `[@][\\v]`, but these always give data either with that same empty string error or the output is completely out of whack.

Comment: Your ends of line are probably \\r\\n. As you said, \\v is *one* vertical whitespace character, but \\r\\n are *two* of them. Just add a + to your regex to collapse successive separators: `[@\\v]+`

Comment: So I could write `[@\\v]+[\\r\\n]`?  I'll have to give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the line break is a `\r\n` pair, and `\v` matches them individually. To replicate this, let's change your code to use an inline string for the test data:

```
String input = "Student @ Codey @ Huntting\r\n" +
               "Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger\r\n";
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("[@\\v]")) {
    for (int tokenNum = 0; scanner.hasNext(); tokenNum++) {
        System.out.println("Token #" + tokenNum + ": \"" + scanner.next() + "\"");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Token #0: "Student "
Token #1: " Codey "
Token #2: " Huntting"
Token #3: ""
Token #4: "Student "
Token #5: " Sarah "
Token #6: " Honsinger"
Token #7: ""
```

One way to fix that is to try matching the `\r\n` pair first:

```
useDelimiter("\r\n|[@\\v]")
```

*Output*

```
Token #0: "Student "
Token #1: " Codey "
Token #2: " Huntting"
Token #3: "Student "
Token #4: " Sarah "
Token #5: " Honsinger"
```

That will however spend time checking `\r` twice, so it would perhaps be better to use the builtin [`\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) *(Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`)*:

```
useDelimiter("@|\\R")
```

Same result, but more clearly reflects how you want to match.

---

You can of course use `trim()` or `strip()` to remove the leading and trailing spaces, but why not make `Scanner` do the work? The use of `|` requires a (non-capturing) group to keep it separate from the whitespace matching:

```
useDelimiter("\\s*(?:@|\\R)\\s*")
```

*Output*

```
Token #0: "Student"
Token #1: "Codey"
Token #2: "Huntting"
Token #3: "Student"
Token #4: "Sarah"
Token #5: "Honsinger"
```

Comment: Aaaaah I think I begin to see!  The only thing I had ever tried was `[@\\v]|\\r\\n`, but it looks like the order of it was messing it up.  Also, I did try the `\\R` but for some reason the Pattern class threw an exception.  I may want to give it another shot.  Also, A+ for figuring out how to get rid of the whitespace!  It was a little annoying to have to write `.trim()` after *every* call to `.next()`

Comment: Beautiful!  Just beautiful!  Even with trailing end lines, it works like a charm!  (Like if I put *two* endlines between "Huntting" and "Student", the scanner skips all of it.)  Also, I must have somehow misused the `\\R` because it works just fine now.

Comment: Hey do you think you could explain to me this last regex you used: `\\s*(?:@|\\R)\\s*`?  I understand the `\\s*` and the `@|\\R` but I don't understand the `?:` or why the whole group is enclosed in parentheses

Comment: @CodeyHuntting The misuse of ``\\R`` might have been trying to do ``[@\\R]``, because ``\\R`` is not a character class (like ``\\s``, ``\\w``, ...), so that will fail to compile. --- If you did ``\\s*@|\\R\\s*``, without `()` grouping, then it's like ``(\\s*@) | (\\R\\s*)``, and that's not what you want, so you do ``\\s* (@|\\R) \\s*``, but that's a [*capturing group*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical), and you don't need the ``@|\\R`` match captured, so instead you use a ``(?:X)`` *non-capturing group*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, we might just want to remove `@` and a space after that, then replace it with new lines and append a text before it. Maybe, this expression would help:

```
([\S\s]*?)(?:@\s|$)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ezf6dX/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

This snippet shows that we likely have a valid expression:

```js
const regex = /([\S\s]*?)(?:@\s|$)/gm;
const str = `Student @ Codey @ Huntting
Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger`;
const subst = `\n$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([\\S\\s]*?)(?:@\\s|$)";
final String string = "Student @ Codey @ Huntting\n"
     + "Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger";
final String subst = "$1\\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

---

If we wish to remove the new lines, we might want to add that to the second capturing group, and the problem might be solved:

```
([\s\S]+?)(@\s|\n\s|\n|$)
```

Here, in the second capturing group `(@\s|\n\s|\n|$)`, using logical OR, we can exclude chars that we do not wish to have:

[image]

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hv1OVH/1/)

```js
const regex = /([\s\S]+?)(@\s|\n\s|\n|$)/gm;
const str = `Student @ Codey @ Huntting

Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger                     
`;
const subst = `Token #: $1\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Java Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([\\s\\S]+?)(@\\s|\\n\\s|\\n|$)";
final String string = "Student @ Codey @ Huntting\n\n"
     + "Student @ Sarah @ Honsinger                     \n";
final String subst = "Token #: $1\\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Comment: No, OP wants to get the *tokens* in the input. The loop to print is simply a minified example for testing the `Scanner.useDelimiter(...)` logic, and we all appreciate a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) *(formerly known as an MCVE)*.

Comment: Ah, okay, so one strategy is just to transform the text into something easier to digest and scan it that way.  I feel this is a little inefficient since we have to operate on the actual input twice, rather than just matching the pattern as we go.  Nevertheless, you're clearly very good with regexes!  Can you think of one that replaces the @ and \n without those extra two \n?

Comment: See, I saw that `\R` in Java's documentation for regexes but for some reason the Pattern class threw a syntax exception when I tried it.  Dunno what's up there

Answer (score 0):

Your file probably contains line breaks of the form `\r\n`.
In that case, your scanner finds the delimiter `\r` and outputs anything before `\r`. Then it finds the delimiter `\n` and outputs the empty token between `\r` and `\n`, then continues after `\n`.

To allow for `\r\n` breaks, I propose you take `\r\n|[@\v]` in that exact order as the delimiter regex. Of course that becomes `"\r\n|[@\\v]"` after escaping.

As Andreas mentioned an other regex you could use is `@|\R`, as `\R` matches any unicode line-break, including `\r\n` together. That's probably even the best solution.

Comment: I substituted this regex into the code sample and it still gave the bad output with the empty string.  I think you're right about the \r\n, though.  I'm just not sure what regex to use to work around it

Comment: Since ``\v`` matches ``\r``, it will match just that and stop, so you still get ``\r\n`` split in two. You need to match ``\r\n`` *first*, i.e. **``\r\n|[@\v]``**, though I would use [``\R``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) instead, i.e. **``@|\R``**